# How to change an unknown number in a text file for C#?

Tags: c#, text-files, discord

I'm trying to create a "warning system" for my Discord Server's bot where when using the command, it'll pull information from a text file and then update it. I can somewhat envision what I want to happen step by step, but I'm confused at how to pull what would be reading from a file as an example:

bob#5368 3
mark#8459 6
cindy#1254 2

I only want to change the number behind the name, which I'm not quite sure how to basically find the user I'm looking for, and then pull the number and set that to 'totalWarn', add it up (totalWarn =+ warnNum), and then update that user with the new number.

Note: 'warningFile' is the file path that's already defined outside of this block of code.

```
public async Task warn(IGuildUser user, int warnNum, [Remainder] string reason)
    {
        int totalWarn = 0;
        if (user == null)
            await ReplyAsync("Please include a name");
        if (warnNum <= 0)
            await ReplyAsync("The warning level must increase by 1 or more.");
        if (reason == null)
            await ReplyAsync("Please include a reason.");

        string nickName = user.Username;

        //Check for whether text file exists or not.
        if (!File.Exists(warningFile))
        {
            //Create the File
            FileStream fs = File.Create(warningFile);
        }

        //Reads all the text in the file and puts it into an array.
        string[] arr = File.ReadAllLines(warningFile);
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
        {
            string line = arr[i];
        }



        totalWarn = +warnNum;
        await Context.Channel.SendMessageAsync($"{user.Username}'s warning level has increased by {warnNum} for {reason}.\n"
            + $"Your warning level is now {totalWarn}. Please take this time to review the server rules.");
    }
```

I'm not looking for somebody to complete it for me, just some help to push myself in the right direction as I'm completely lost, and the information regarding changing text isn't quite helpful.

Comment: Does the `user.Username` property return only the name? You need to have the whole identifier to get the actual user in the file

Comment: So what is problem? You need a help with parsing "bob#5368 3" string?

Comment: You likely want to use a database for this.  With your approach you have to read in _all_ the lines of your text file (when you only need one).  Then you have to parse the line of text, find the number you want, parse that number into an `int` then add to that `int`, and then rewrite the entire file.  Whereas a database would be much less work, and much faster

Comment: FYI, you will get an exception if the file doesn't exist, because you're not closing the `FileStream fs` after creating a new file, and then you attempt to read the file in the next line. To solve this, you could either put it in a `using`, which will close and dispose of it automatically: `using (File.Create(warningFile)){}` (best) or just close it after you create it by: `File.Create(warningFile).Close();`

Comment: I wasn't expecting all these comments so quickly. The user.Username pulls their current nickname that they have in Discord, I'm not quite sure how to change the identifier to a string.

I'll definitely check out the database approach. I have zero experience with such things, so I wasn't sure how easy it would be to incorporate that into a discord bot.

As for the file closing, noted. Forgot to write that in. Fixed on my actual program for now.

Answer (score 3):

Here is how to parse a line from the file using regex:

```
void Main()
{
    string line = "bob#5368 3";
    GuildUser user = new GuildUser( line );
    user.Warnings++;
    user.ToString().Dump();
}

public class GuildUser
{
    public string Name { get; set;}
    public int Id { get; set;}
    public int Warnings { get; set;}
    public GuildUser( string line )
    {
        Match match = Regex.Match( line, @"(.+)?#(\d+) (\d+)" );
        if ( !match.Success ) throw new Exception( "Couldn't parse line: " + line );
        Name = match.Groups[1].Value;
        Id = int.Parse( match.Groups[2].Value );
        Warnings = int.Parse( match.Groups[3].Value );

    }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"{Name}#{Id} {Warnings}";
    }
}
```

You could use File.ReadAllLines, File.WriteAllLines.

I'd probably use some linq as well.

I updated to add a "ToString" method to rewrite the line.
Then you can just add to the warnings and get the new string calling ToString().

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

```
    public static void stuff()
    {       
        string name = "bob";
        string firstNumber = "";
        string secondNumber = "";
        int lineIndex = 0;

        List<string> lines = new List<string>(File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Text.txt"));

        foreach(string line in lines)
        {
            if(line.Contains(name))
            {
                lineIndex = lines.IndexOf(line);
                string[] parts = line.Split('#');
                name = parts[0];
                firstNumber = parts[1].Split(' ')[0];   
                secondNumber = parts[1].Split(' ')[1];

                firstNumber = (Convert.ToInt32(firstNumber) + 1).ToString();

                /*
                 * instert code here for changing the number you want to change
                */

                lines[lineIndex] = name + "#" + firstNumber + " " + secondNumber;
                File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\Text.txt",lines.ToArray());
                break;
            }
        }                   
    }
```